# issue with pagination and multiple checkbox selection

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a table with pagination enabled and I'm using  `p-tableHeaderCheckbox` to select checkboxes in all rows

if my `rowsPerPageOptions` is set to 50 and I checkec my `p-tableHeaderCheckbox` all the rows will get selected(row from 50-100 also get selected)

Now It should select only first 50 rows instead of 50 to 100 and so on...

Comment: can you give more details about this? your question is very unclear.

Comment: Could you please create a StackBlitz example, should help us resolve the issue..Thanks

Comment: open this link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NYlsyLsHEPADiZGt1K5kTFoEU_VBy_30x2XsgUvwyh8/edit